# How to use Javascript to get a visitors monitor resolution?

Tags: javascript, css, resolution

I'm building a website for Advanced Web Design and I'm stuck on something. I want the content of the page (contained in a `<div>`) to be centered. Using CSS I tried this:

```
body {text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;}
```

That didn't seem to work. I know you can detect a browsers resolution using Javascript, and I got to thinking. How would I detect the width, and use that to set the left and right margins of the body? It would be `((resolutionWidth - 800) / 2)` to determine the margins that I need (the `<div>` is `800px` wide).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin: 0 auto` is one of the easiest ways to center content on a website. Don't use JS to center the content unless you absolutely have to.

Check out this jsFiddle on how to use `margin: 0 auto`: http://jsfiddle.net/NfRtV/

Answer (score 0):

`margin: auto` only works if the element has a width. Try specifying the width and retesting your code!

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQjVL/2

```
body { 
  width: 500px; 
  margin: auto; 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  text-align: center; 
 }
```

You can't detect their monitor resolution, but you can detect the screen width and height. Those are accessible via javascript. Although you obviously shouldn't do it that way because there is a CSS method to do so.

```
  viewportwidth = window.innerWidth;
  viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
```

Comment: You can use `position: relative` as well on the `body` element: http://jsfiddle.net/5Td5Q/

Comment: woops, updated my answer. First response was wrong. The element just needs a width.

Answer (score 0):

Set your width in the same element as your `auto` margins.  So something like this:

```
#page { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

In some versions of IE, this doesn't work, so wrap a `div` around this element, giving it `text-align: center`, and reset in a child div.

Example markup:

```
<body>
  <div id="ie-page-center">
    <div id="page">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Example CSS:

```
#ie-page-center { text-align: center; }
#page { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<script language="javascript"> alert('Width:' + screen.width+ ' & Height: ' +screen.height); </script>
```